# Is there any way to rescue a question the OP is done with

Tags: discussion, questions

I was just [involved in a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23449370/794234) where the OP was describing seemingly impossible behavior.  The OP had not posted enough source code to identify the issue.  [Someone answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23449606/794234) with what looks like a *complete guess*.  There is not enough info in either the question or the answer to identify a problem or a solution, someone just fiddled with the code enough that it started working.

In this kind of question, is there anything to do to rescue the question now that the OP has moved on?  There might be a very good question/answer in that problem.  I definitely don't know what caused it (based on the solution, my guess in comments was wrong).

Comment: Close as "not enough information to diagnose problem".

Comment: This is why it is important that poor questions get closed quickly.  They are a magnet for bad answers if that doesn't happen.  Only thing left now is to get enough delete votes after it gets closed, pretty unlikely to happen.  One bad question requiring *ten* votes to get rid of, that's a massive scaling problem.

Comment: @HansPassant perhaps the rules for deletion votes should be changed. I can understand why it would take more votes to delete **duplicate** questions that have good, useful answers, but what good does it serve to keep around answers to **non-duplicate, bad questions?** Especially if they're closed as such `:/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling Answers Containing "I can't reproduce that"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274519/handling-answers-containing-i-cant-reproduce-that)

Comment: It seems to me that a good answer to a bad question would include *why* the answer solved the problem, and would become the rescue that you're suggesting.  A *fiddled with* answer that just happens to work (and nobody knows why) doesn't really strike me as a learning or documentation opportunity for the community.  In this case, *either* the OP or the answerer could make that rescue and update the question to be definitive.  Barring that, I'd certainly vote to close a poorly-constructed question that had a random-ish answer.