# Handling Answers Containing "I can't reproduce that"

Tags: discussion, answers

***The question I am referring to:*** *[How to “escape” a comma in a PHP argument value so it doesn't separate them into multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386215/how-to-escape-a-comma-in-a-php-argument-value-so-it-doesnt-separate-them-into)*

Using the information given by OP, the problem definitely can't be reproduced. This is a problem I see quite often (as it can be difficult for beginners to create a Minimal/Complete/Verifiable example), and I'm not sure how it should be handled.

---

I almost always comment on the post with a link to an example that proves OP code valid and ask for an update.  Occasionally, I will use the close reason "off-topic because..."

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

However, that seems a little harsh sometimes since I wouldn't necessarily say the question is "off-topic"..the user just may need to update their question after seeing my comment and realizing that the issue is different from what they though (or should they be closing and re-opening?).

---

In this question, however, someone (quite reputable) posted an answer with example code and said "I can't reproduce that". I immediately flagged the answer as "It is not an answer" and commented:

> I was just about to post the same thing, however probably is better as a comment.

I then did my typical comment to OP about the code not being reproducible and elected to put in my close vote for the above reason.

---

After seeing the 201k reputation from the person who answered "I can't reproduce that", I kind of shoved my foot in my mouth. Should I not have flagged his answer? Should I be posting my examples of valid code on questions that aren't reproducible? And finally, is this the right time to use the close reason "off-topic"?

Comment: It just goes to show that even 201k users sometimes ignore the rules. That's not an answer, that's a comment, and I flagged it as such.

Comment: @MartijnPieters good to know I took the right action there. Does a question like this, that can't be reproduced, deserve to be closed? Or should the OP just be alerted with a comment and urged to update their question?

Comment: I once "other"-flagged a fairly long "can't reproduce" answer with the message, "This answer essentially says, 'I can't reproduce your issue.' It shouldn't be an answer, but rather a a series of comments..." The flag was declined with the reason, "I see no reason to delete this. It does have helpful information in an attempt to answer the question." Some "can't reproduce" answers are acceptable, apparently.

Comment: Closing is not the end of the road, but does force the OP to take responsibility for fixing the issue. Don't assume the OP will add the information, just close, and we can always reopen again when the info *is* added.

Comment: @MartijnPieters great point! I forget about the re-opens once a closed question is edited. That probably seems like the best way to get the attention of OP as well.

Comment: Meh, this all worked out fine.  You can treat it like an unreproducable problem and close it, if you like, but the answer is an answer; saying it isn't is just legalistic maneuvering.  Note that another moderator has already reviewed those three mod flags, dismissed them as helpful, but took no action on the answer.  I agree.

Comment: @RobertHarvey can you elaborate (maybe in an answer here) on why you/SO think that the answer would be considered an answer?

Comment: Because it's not spam, gibberish, or an attempt to communicate with some other user; it directly addresses the question that was asked.  The only action that a moderator can take is to remove what appears to be useful information by deleting the answer; we won't do that.

Comment: Okay @RobertHarvey I suppose I can see that. The [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) says that answers that "do not fundamentally answer the question", though. While "I can't reproduce the problem" isn't spam or a comment, does it really *answer* the question?

Comment: Ah, but if you continue reading through the bullets in the Help Center article you reference, I think you'll find that the answer is none of those things.

Comment: I think it could be debated that "I can't reproduce the problem" counts as "commentary on the question". I guess this is where we disagree. Anyways, are we coming to the conclusion that the question deserves close votes but an answer like this does not deserve flags?

Comment: The only reasonable action that a moderator can take here is "convert to comment."  This particular answer doesn't seem to warrant that.  The code formatting would get majorly borked.  Remember, we're all here to be helpful, and bad things are not happening on this post unless useful information gets lost.

Comment: Makes sense, I agree that his particular answer can't be a comment (although I believe it could be thrown in a gist of sorts). Anyways, thanks for the discussion!

Comment: I think an explanation of why "this question does not have an answer", for whatever reason, is a valid answer.  However, if the entire "answer" is "I can't reproduce that", and there is no other detail or discussion, that probably belongs in a comment.

Comment: And let's also keep in mind that often a "comment" requires formatted code, or is sufficiently long that it does not fit into the comment format.  Such comments, if reasonably valid, should be allowed as "answers", even when they do not directly answer the question.  To insist otherwise is arbitrary censorship.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes to your first comment, no to your second.  The presence of code does not automatically make a comment an answer.  Also, censorship doesn't exist on Stack Overflow; there's no "right to free speech" here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - So how would you propose making a "comment" that requires formatted code, or whose length is greater than what's allowed?

Comment: @HotLicks: You don't.

Comment: Essentially this answer just says "I don't know".  That's a bit useless in a resource that's supposed to be a collection of useful questions and answers.  I mean ... I also don't know the answer to the OP's problem - should I post that too?  The respondent should have known better than to post this, and this answer deserves downvotes for being "not useful".  What baffles me is that OP accepted this answer.  I thought accepting an answer was saying "this is the answer that solved my problem" - which in this case, it clearly didn't.

Comment: The actual answer given (by MarcB) is a terrific and full answer.  If MarcB had happened to type "Here's how to do it.." or "Here's the answer..." none of this idiotic discussion would have happened. It's just incredible that there seems to be a Thing developing on SO where an answerer has to type "Here Is The Answer:" to legalistically avoid crazed "that's not an answer!" attacks.  So, so ridiculous.

Comment: @JoeBlow, the discussion would've happened either way. I was about to post a comment saying "this is not reproducible" when I saw an answer saying the same thing (elaborated). I flagged it, commented on his answer, close voted the question, and came here because I was baffled that that could be considered an answer (and he had 200k rep).

Comment: @DavidWallace: "Your problem is not reproducible as described, and here's the proof" and "I don't know" are two vastly different things.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I disagree.  "This works for me" is exactly the same as "I don't know what you did wrong".

Answer (score 10):

### Should you have flagged his answer?

Robert Harvey said:

> Note that another moderator has already reviewed those three mod
> flags, dismissed them as helpful, but took no action on the answer. I
> agree.

When asked to elaborate on why this counts as an answer, he replied:

> Because it's not spam, gibberish, or an attempt to communicate with
> some other user; it directly addresses the question that was asked.
> The only action that a moderator can take is to remove what appears to
> be useful information by deleting the answer; we won't do that.

[An SE community blog post from 2011](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2011/09/september-2011-newsletter/) advises:

> **Flags should be closed as `[helpful]` under most circumstances.** If you feel strongly that a question was flagged in bad faith, it is okay
> to mark it `[declined]`. But try to err on the side of clearing as
> `[helpful]` whenever the user is trying to be genuinely helpful, *even
> if you do not necessarily act on the flag.*

For other possible interpretations of why the other, unidentified moderator might have marked the flags as "helpful" without removing the question, see the meta.SE FAQ, [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105391/254929)

The conclusion you can draw from all of this is that while the flags were seen as being made in good faith, they were unnecessary, and you should not flag similar answers in the future.

### Should you post examples of valid code on questions that aren't reproducible?

Useful information that directly addresses the question that was asked may qualify as an answer when it's also reasonably comprehensive. If it turns out that someone else is able to demonstrate a way to reproduce the problem after all, your answer will probably suffer in one way or another. Keep that in mind when deciding whether to comment or answer.

You also may not want to answer a question that you feel should be closed. Related reading:

- [How to decide which questions I should not answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254549/2359271)
- [Closing Etiquette: Why Do Some Answer *and* Close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4283/254929)

### Is this the right time to close as "off-topic"?

Yes. Let's go through the criteria:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be
> reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**.

This criterion is met because the problem cannot be reproduced.

> While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in
> a manner unlikely to help future readers.

This one asks us to make a prediction, so you may have to use your best judgment. In this case, the criterion is clearly met in hindsight, given [the OP's comment that the problem was actually with a regular expression, "somewhere else in the code."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386215/how-to-escape-a-comma-in-a-php-argument-value-so-it-doesnt-separate-them-into#comment41429814_26386215)

> This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the
> shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before
> posting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

This is sort of a half-anti-criterion; if an MCVE was provided, then clearly the question is reproducible, but an MCVE doesn't necessarily rule out a typographical error. In this case, there's no MCVE, so the point is moot. This question passes the test with flying colors; your vote to close was warranted and [has since been confirmed by a moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26386215/revisions). Related reading:

- [The War of the Closes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/)
- [Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/254929)

Comment: Glad to know the consensus is that a "off-topic" close of the question is warranted and a flag on the answer isn't abusive. I guess the main thing I was looking for was this: *"Useful information that directly addresses the question that was asked may qualify as an answer when it's also reasonably comprehensive."* If that is the community consensus, I'll take it (although it seems from the above comments that there was some disagreement). Thanks!

Comment: @Sam I don't know that I would claim this to be the community consensus just yet. I made the answer CW because it relies heavily on other users' words, and so that it can be *adjusted* to reflect consensus if my initial reading of those words was inaccurate.

Comment: Point being, until more users have read/edited/voted up the wiki answer, consider everything in it (other than direct quotes) to be subject to change.

Comment: Fair point. I think I, and most, agree with mostly everything. The last point that seems to be debated is whether or not the answer in question is a valid answer. I see arguments for both.

Comment: True, which is why I relied almost entirely on the words and actions of elected moderators in addressing that point.

Comment: Glad to know that `This question was *solved* by a problem` was finally changed to **caused**. Makes that flag a whole lot more useful.

Comment: I don't think that guidance holds any longer.  Flags can now also be resolved as 'disputed', meaning that the mod understands that a reasonable person could think the way you did, and doesn't want to penalize you because there was no malice, but still you were wrong to flag the post.

Comment: @BenVoigt If I'm [reading this meta.SE post correctly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95275/254929), 'disputed' has a different meaning. I don't have the free time to do more research at the moment so there may be more to the story.